# Will 11.04 use other filesystem than ext4?

Tags: 11.04, filesystem

I heard something of a filesystem change. Is it gonna happen in 11.04?

Comment: Where might you have heard this?

Comment: It was [widely reported](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ODI1Mg) last year that it was a possibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: no, we're sticking with ext4 by default.

However btrfs support has been improved for 11.04 (btrfs can be your boot partition). It may well be adapted as a future release's default - see the Ubuntu's Development Manager's [blog post from last year on the subject](http://netsplit.com/2010/05/14/btrfs-by-default-in-maverick/).