# btrfs default file system for Natty?

Tags: 11.04, default, btrfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will 11.04 use other filesystem than ext4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22636/will-11-04-use-other-filesystem-than-ext4)

Will btrfs be the **default** file system in Natty Narwhal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, brtfs is not stable yet. Unacceptable performance issues have been reported on common use cases.

Comment: Random use case: It works for me though. The compression support in btrfs can bring a significant speed gain for small SSDs in netbooks.